# 404 not found when accessing www

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, iis-8

I tried:

`www Host(A) 38.67.136.195`

And everytime you accessed my site using www.synergyweight.com then it gave a 404 error.

So I changed it up using a Cname

`www Alias(CNAME) synergyweight.com`

Neiter one will work.

I can ping www.synergyweight.com, but nothing is being displayed except Not Found error and it's not an asp.net error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your IIS instance is not set up with the bindings necessary to accept requests for www.synergyweight.com.

Check the bindings for this site and make sure that you have an entry that specifies the FQDN 'www.synergyweight.com'

Your DNS is set up fine.